# How to find locations for hydro power using raster analysis?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, raster, dem

I have a stream network and DEM file both in raster format. I need to extract values from DEM to stream network. For the analysis in stream network after that, I need to find out the places for hydro power based on various criteria of head, stream order. 
So how can i start my work?

I am planning to convert both raster file into text file using numpy array and extracting head for all the cells of stream and after that i will start processing. Is that a good idea to start or is there any other way?

I am quite new to python.

Comment: You don't specify which GIS system you intend to use?

Comment: I would prefer to use ArcGIS

Comment: Six months have passed since you asked this question and I notice that you have not accepted the one answer.  Assuming that the reason is that it did not offer the ArcGIS solution you were seeking, are you perhaps able to use the edit button to revise your question to be what you may still be looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would suggest searching if already there's a tool that can make what you want.Grass for example has an extensive array of hydrological functions. If you provide a rough example on what you want to do (what do you mean by 'textfile'?) we might be able to suggest you where too look.

Python is quite powerful and it can do what you want, but don't expect to create complex custom gis applications.

for starters I would suggest reading [Chris Garrard](http://www.gis.usu.edu/~chrisg/python/2009/) excellent tutorials on the subject to take a taste how gdal and python works together, and move your way up. Also since you're new to python I also suggest getting yourself some books - the good/bad thing about python is that it comes with a VAST ready to use libraries, but you (and me) don't half of them. A good starting book is [Wesley Chun's Core PYTHON Programming](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Core-PYTHON-Programming-Wesley-Chun/dp/0132269937/ref=pd_bxgy_b_img_y). You can also take a look at [OSGeos book](http://www.osgeo.org/books) section.

Hope it helps.